# SQL query to get only image name with extension without complete path from SQL table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in a table that saves image along with the path.

Below are few image path examples:

```
    /Products_images/Essentials/111219_Essent_Org_Red_Clsd-XL.jpg
    /ul/products/1417/130514-Montecito-20-spinner-French-Roast.jpg
    /ul/products/1470/130419_RodeoDrive_20HybridRed-M.jpg
    /ul/newproducts/266-07-437-TVC-main.jpg
```

When i use sql query:

```
select Image from Product
```

It returns complete image path as it should be.

How can i fetch only image name with extension from this image column without the image path.

So my required result should be:

```
111219_Essent_Org_Red_Clsd-XL.jpg
130514-Montecito-20-spinner-French-Roast.jpg
130419_RodeoDrive_20HybridRed-M.jpg
266-07-437-TVC-main.jpg
```

Is there any way to get this directly using sql query and not using c# code.

Is there any Substring or Regex in SQL Server.

I would be very thank full for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in SQL? It's a lot easier to use eg `Path.GetFileName()` in C#

Comment: I'd recommend you split directory and filename _before_ you store it in the DB. You can even create a persisted computed field (`Image AS DirectoryName + FileName PERSISTED`) so you still have your combined path available. If you use your file name in a `WHERE` this should also perform much better and you can index any field that you need.

Comment: Actually i am exporting lot of data from a table into excel file. You are correct it can be done through c# but i wanted to fetch directly from database.         Banshi Gurjar and Abhishek's answer worked perfectly for my case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it

```
declare @a VARCHAR(200)
set @a = ' /Products_images/Essentials/111219_Essent_Org_Red_Clsd-XL.jpg'

select right(@a, charindex('/', reverse(@a)) - 1) as filename
```

In your case

```
Select right(ColumnName, charindex('/', reverse(ColumnName)) - 1) as filename From TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it -

```
DECLARE @Image TABLE (Imagepath VARCHAR(2000))
INSERT INTO @Image(Imagepath)
SELECT '/Products_images/Essentials/111219_Essent_Org_Red_Clsd-XL.jpg' UNION
SELECT    '/ul/products/1417/130514-Montecito-20-spinner-French-Roast.jpg' UNION 
SELECT    '/ul/products/1470/130419_RodeoDrive_20HybridRed-M.jpg' UNION
SELECT    '/ul/newproducts/266-07-437-TVC-main.jpg'
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Imagepath),1,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(Imagepath))-1)) FROM @Image
```

Answer (score 0):

when you got your image name and path in your string you can use the split function to get the last item after the `/`

try this:

```
string onlyImageName = stringFullPathAndName.Split('/').Last();
```

Comment: That's *not* a good idea. First, `Path.GetFileName()` already does that. Second, split generates a lot of unnecessary temporary strings

Answer (score 0):

Use **SQL Functions** to extract only the file names:

```
SELECT
 LTRIM(
  RTRIM(
   REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
     REVERSE(ImagePath),
     0,
     CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(ImagePath),0)
    )
   )
  )
 ) AS FilenameOnly
FROM SomeTable
```

[image: Fname]

Comment: Thanks this also worked. i am bit novice in SQL could you please help me to understand the use 0 in REVERSE and CHARINDEX function.